# When PIA is running, you can no longer access the application to connect to a different VPN. It's no longer in the notifications panel

Tags: internet, vpn, openvpn

When Private Internet Access is running on Elementary OS, it launches and goes in the background. You cannot access it in the notifications pane.

When you go and try to run it again, it will never show the settings. So, if you connected to one VPN on setup, you can no longer set up another VPN server.

Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for this

Install PIA as seen on the [site](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/installer/download_installer_linux).

Then edit pia_manager.desktop

```
sudo nano ~/.local/share/applications/pia_manager.desktop
```

And alter the line `Exec=/home/bats/.pia_manager/pia_manager/run.sh`

So it becomes like this:

```
Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity /home/bats/.pia_manager/pia_manager/run.sh
```

The icon will then appear on the panel.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with the PIA app, so I uninstalled it and configured the VPN through eOS's network configuration. No problems so far.